# Append values in the same key of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How to add different values in the same key of a dictionary? These different values are added 
in a loop.

Below is what I desired entries in the dictionary `data_dict`

`data_dict = {}
 And during each iterations, output should looks like:
 Iteration1 -> {'HUBER': {'100': 5.42}}
 Iteration2 -> {'HUBER': {'100': 5.42, '10': 8.34}}
 Iteration3 -> {'HUBER': {'100': 5.42, '10': 8.34, '20': 7.75}} etc`

However, at the end of the iterations, data_dict is left with the last entry only:

```
{'HUBER': {'80': 5.50}}
```

Here's the code:

```
import glob

path = "./meanFilesRun2/*.txt"
all_files = glob.glob(path)
data_dict = {}  

def func_(all_lines, method, points, data_dict):

   if method == "HUBER":
       mean_error = float(all_lines[-1]) # end of the file contains total_error
       data_dict["HUBER"] = {points: mean_error}
       return data_dict

   elif method == "L1":
       mean_error = float(all_lines[-1])
       data_dict["L1"] = {points: mean_error}
       return data_dict

for file_ in all_files:
   lineMthds = file_.split("_")[1] # reading line methods like "HUBER/L1/L2..."
   algoNum = file_.split("_")[-2] # reading diff. algos number used like "1/2.."
   points = file_.split("_")[2] # diff. points used like "10/20/30..."

   if algoNum == "1":
      FI = open(file_, "r")
      all_lines = FI.readlines()        

      data_dict = func_(all_lines, lineMthds, points, data_dict)           
      print data_dict
      FI.close()
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for the loop, and how you're adding the data during each iteration ?

Comment: It is little bit complicated. I put it in anyway.

Comment: You are trying to add another dictionary ryt ?
You can call a function which modifies the value for the key 'HUBER' and then assigns back to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) here. Currently the problem with your code is that in each call to `func_` you're re-assigning `data_dict["HUBER"]` to a new dict.

Change:

```
data_dict["HUBER"] = {points: mean_error}
```

to:

```
data_dict.setdefault("HUBER", {})[points] = mean_error
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use defaultdict from the collections module:

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
d['HUBER']['100'] = 5.42
d['HUBER']['10'] = 3.45
```